# get the selected row number randomly return 0

Tags: c#

I have a context menu strip linked to a DGV. When a cell in the DGV is clicked, it will open the context menu strip and I can click on "plotStripMenuItem" to open up a form (formPlot) which basically reads data from a text file and plots graphs and calculates some stats that will be returned (once the formPlot closed) to the previously clicked row of the DGV.

to do this i use "int clickedRow" to store the clicked row number before opening the formPlot, and use that to update the DGV after i close formPlot.

```
    private void plotToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the row number which was clicked 
        string strClickedRow = DGVLeft.CurrentCellAddress.Y.ToString();
        int clickedRow = Convert.ToInt16(strClickedRow);

        FormPlot formPlot = new FormPlot(strLot, pathLD);
        formPlot.ShowDialog();

        DGVLeft.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[0].Value = formPlot.columnA;
        DGVLeft.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[1].Value = formPlot.ColumnB;
        DGVLeft.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[2].Value = formPlot.columnC;
        DGVLeft.Rows[clickedRow].Cells[3].Value = formPlot.columnD;
    }
```

Most of the time this works as expected. But i noticed it occasionally doesn't update the DGV cells that was clicked before I opened formPlot. Instead, it updated row number 0!

e.g. I clicked row 7 but upon returning from formPlot, the value of DGV row 0 was the one got updated. Not the value of DGV row number 7.

To me there is now way that the row 0 would be the one get updated, as i clicked row 7 and stored it in a variable.

am i missing something here?

Comment: any reason why `ColumnB` is capitalized, but `columnA`, `columnC`, and `columnD` are not?

Comment: as for your actual error, what I'd so is put a break-point at  `int clickedRow = Convert.ToInt16(strClickedRow);`, and see what `strClickedRow` is when the error happens.  I think it might be `null`

Comment: oh that one just because i wrongly use capital for ColumnB when declaring the string in formPlot

Comment: i will try to debug at int clickedRow = Convert.ToInt16(strClickedRow).

Comment: the problem is that most of the time the code works as expected. So it is difficult to catch the error.

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can put conditions on your breakpoints so that they only get hit in specific circumstances.  Weeding out specific values (or sets of values) can help a lot.

Comment: Are there any other events that fire on your grid?

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not solve your problem, but why are you converting the row number to a string and back again?

```
    //get the row number which was clicked 
    string strClickedRow = DGVLeft.CurrentCellAddress.Y.ToString();
    int clickedRow = Convert.ToInt16(strClickedRow);
```

should just be

```
    //get the row number which was clicked 
    int clickedRow = DGVLeft.CurrentCellAddress.Y;
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that. i converted it to string coz i i thought i needed it for something else before, but apparently not, and i forgot to just use the int. I will test without the string and see if i can replicate the problem.

Comment: seems like the problem still happens without the string.

Comment: it is weird because the problem often only happens once and the rest of the day it will never appear again. sometimes the problem happens when the program first fired up. sometimes it works as expected straight from the beginning and started to play up later on.